# How to scroll down browser page - Laravel Dusk (Browser Tests)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm preparing tests using [Browser Tests (Laravel Dusk)][1]

[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk and I need force click to element which is not see  before scroll down browser page. How can define in dusk test to click unsee element or scroll browser page ?

```
class SliderTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser
                    ->visit('http://localhost:8000/admin/login')                    
                    ->click('label[for=test_1]')
                    ->pause(500)
                ;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the answer from @james

you can execute scripts, but these cannot be chained. So you can just execute the scroll before the click occurs.

```
public function testExample()
{
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser
                ->visit('http://localhost:8000/admin/login')
                ->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 500);'); 
                // can't chain methods after this
        $browser                    
                ->click('label[for=test_1]')
                ->pause(500) //you can keep chaining here;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use now the `script` method:

`$browser->script('window.scrollTo(0, 500);');`

Answer (score 4):

If you know how far you have to scroll, you could try:

```
$browser->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 500);');
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. When I try I receive error: `Error: Call to a member function pause() on null`

Answer (score 1):

### Now supported by laravel/dusk 6.0

the implementation they use: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5eb7fa57346fd39b3b38e4c4bdd5ca177d1ac711/src/Browser.php#L282-L297

```
public function scrollTo($selector)
{
    $this->ensurejQueryIsAvailable();

    $selector = $this->resolver->format($selector);

    $this->driver->executeScript("jQuery(\"html, body\").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(\"$selector\").offset().top}, 0);");

    return $this;
}
```

### DIY implementation

Extend the browser class and add the following method:

```
public function scrollTo($elementSelector)
{
   return $this->driver->executeScript("document.querySelector('$elementSelector').scrollIntoView()");
}
```

then you can scroll to a selector:

```
$browser->scrollTo("#elementId");
```

Comment: Now available in the core of Dusk albeit a slightly different method of scrolling: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5eb7fa57346fd39b3b38e4c4bdd5ca177d1ac711/src/Browser.php#L282-L297

Comment: Thanks for notification

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sweep over the entire page you can use the following codes

```
$this->browse(function(Browser $browser){
    $browser->visit('http://localhost:8000/admin/login')
    
    ->script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)');

   //The above returns an array, but not the $browser object. Therefore, the output cannot be chained.

    $browser->pause(500)
    ->click('label[for=test_1]');  
    
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use Laravel guides, You should use the ``
like below:

```
$browser->scrollIntoView('.selector')
        ->click('.selector');
```

and laravel documentaion link [Laravel 9 doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#scrolling-an-element-into-view)